# what regex library does bash use

Tags: regex, bash

I am teaching myself bash scripting and the first element that I am learning right now is regular expressions. I am learning regular expressions through a video that I purchased, and the regex tester that the instructor has me use to test with is RegexPal which is a tester specifically for java-script regexe's. Could someone please tell me the type, or library of regex's that bash uses? I want to make sure that I am learning the proper content to be able to use in bash scripting. I know that RegexBuddy is an option, but which one of the type of regex's would I use if I would ultimately using them in bash. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: The Bash regex engine is a little limited. I would highly recommend learning regex with Perl and any skills you would learn would be easily applied to bash regex.

Comment: Thank you Samuel. I will do as you suggest.

Comment: regexp's are not use very often in bash! globs are used more frequently. Otherwise, it uses the POSIX regex functions, the `man` of which being at `man 3 regex` (on my system).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Better to use `man re_format`to get an overview - seems to work on OS X and Linux distributions.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed as an off-topic thread. It's a question about programing (shell scripting, regex, perl...) Isn't it ?

Comment: The question has value, if its focus became a request for a high-level overview of regexes in bash and the various utilities that accept regexes - including the many, many associated pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Bash regex used are fairly standard. Example:

```
[[ $var =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "it's a number"
```

The range of values ​​(`[0-9]` for example), the `^` symbol to indicate the start, the `$` symbol to indicate the end, the number of occurrences (`+` for one or more, `*` for 0 or more, `{n, m}` for between n and m occurrences, `{n}` for strictly n occurrences, ...). They are found in all languages which allow us to use regular expressions.

So I think that any manufacturing regex tool may be used for that (with a few adjustments. For example in PHP there are delimiters, in some languages ​​there are shortcuts like `\d` for digits, ...).

However, Bash is quite limited but may be accompanied by other tools such as `egrep` ( `grep -E`), `sed` or `awk` ...

Anyway, before using manufacturing regex tools, I think that you must know the syntax of regex to be able to know whether the proposal of tool is correct or not.

Comment: Just what i wanted to know. Thank you Idriss.

Comment: @JudeT.Bonham Don't forget to mark this subject as solved ;)